# Squaring vector elements recursively

Tags: c++, math, vector

So I've been struggling with how to square vector elements recursively... So if I have a vector sample = {2,3,4}, the function needs to return a vector with 4,9,16. Any advice?

Comment: Why recursively? It is trivial to do non-recursively. Is recursion a hard requirement?

Comment: Yes it must be done recursively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example looks like recursively:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

void recursiveSquare (std::vector <int> & data, const int index)
{
    std::cout << "Function call for element: " << index << std::endl;
    if (index != data.size () - 1) {
        recursiveSquare (data, index + 1);
    }
    std::cout << "Modified element: " << index << std::endl;
    data [index] *= data [index];
};

void print (const std::string & header, std::vector <int> & data)
{
    std::cout << header;
    for (const auto & a : data) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main (int /*argc*/, char ** /*argv*/)
{
    std::vector <int> data {2, 3, 4};

    print ("Input: ", data);
    recursiveSquare (data, 0);
    print ("Output: ", data);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
Input: 2 3 4 
Function call for element: 0
Function call for element: 1
Function call for element: 2
Modified element: 2
Modified element: 1
Modified element: 0
Output: 4 9 16
```